# How to get variable/inconstant checkbox id and values in j query?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I am getting all the community name from sql database and showing drop-down with checkbox. for that i am using for-each loop to show values.

Below is my code fetching $results array from database and showing it in the check box

```
    <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Columns">
    Columns
    <b class="caret">
    </b>
   </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <?php  foreach( $results as $result){ 
    ?>
    <li>
    <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $result['community_name']; ?>" 
    name="multiselect" value="<?php echo $result['community_name']; ?>"><? 
    php echo $result['community_name']; ?></input>
    </label>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

So how to fetch all the checked and unchecked values in Jquery ??

Please help

Thnks

Comment: Adding some sensible code indention would go a long way when it comes to readability of your code.

Comment: Also, input-elements are self closing elements, like this: `<input ... />`, not: `<input ....></input>`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a common `className` to each checkbox so that it will be easy to query the elements having the same class. Also, note that `<input />` element is empty, it can contain only attributes, no body.

```js
var cb = $('.cb');
var cbValue = cb.map((index, el) => {
  return el.checked;
});
console.log('cbValue', JSON.stringify(cbValue));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Columns">
    Columns
    <b class="caret">
    </b>
   </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <label class="checkbox" for="1">1</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="multiselect" value="" class="cb" checked />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="checkbox" for="2">2</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="multiselect" value="" class="cb" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="checkbox" for="3">3</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="multiselect" value="" class="cb" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      console.log($(this).attr('id'), "checked")
    } else {
      console.log($(this).attr('id'), "Unchecked")
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Form control: inline checkbox</h2>
    <p>The form below contains three inline checkboxes:</p>
    <form>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" id="opt1">Option 1
    </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" id="opt2">Option 2
    </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox"id="opt3">Option 3
    </label>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```